# How can I forbid users to type numbers in a NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I forbid users to type numbers in a NSTextField ?

I'm currently using a custom NSFormatter showing a popup **after** the users typed the value, but how can I prevent the inserting right after typing instead ?

thanks

I've tried this and it almost work.. but if I type a number and then some letters i.e. "24jdf" the letters are still displayed (even if removed when the field looses focus).

```
- (BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString *)partialString newEditingString:(NSString **)newString errorDescription:(NSString **)error
//- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id *)obj forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString  **)error
{   

    if ([self numberFromString:partialString] == nil)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to subclass your `NSFormatter` and override the following method:

```
-(BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString **)partialStringPtr proposedSelectedRange:(NSRangePointer)proposedSelRangePtr originalString:(NSString *)origString originalSelectedRange:(NSRange)origSelRange errorDescription:(NSString **)error {
   NSString *string = *partialStringPtr;
   NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
   return (NSNotFound == [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:numbers].location);
}
```

Comment: If I type a number and then some letters i.e. "24jdf" the letters are still displayed (even if removed when the field looses focus).

Comment: ??? You said you didn't want *numbers* to be displayed. The above code should work, are you subclassing NSFormatter or NSNumberFormatter or what?

Comment: Ya sorry. I actually don't want letters to be displayed.. so I've changed the last line to return !(NSNotFound == [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:numbers].location);

Comment: However, if I first type numbers and then letters, the letters are displayed (but they are not validated, so in the end it works, it keeps only the numbers). Would be nice to not display them while typing as well.